# echo Javascript window.location.href not working

Tags: php, javascript, navigation, echo

I have a function which echoes javascript to navigate to a different page. While navigation occurs, the

```
echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
```

does not work and simply prints it on the screen.

```
"window.location.href="./index.php";
```

I use my function this way: `redirect("./index.php");`

My php function is as follows

```
  function redirect($url)
   {    
    if (!headers_sent())
    {    
      header('Location: '.$url);
      exit;
    }
   else
    {      
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
      echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
      echo '</script>';
      echo '<noscript>';
      echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
      echo '</noscript>'; exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your $url should be properly escaped in case it contains a ".  Anyway, is the page an html page?  The browser might be interpretting it as plain text.  Also, being a bit pedantic, the HTTP specification dictates that Location should have a full URI following it, not a relative URL.

Comment: Its a php page. My project requires me to give relative URL's hence I have no choice for that.

Comment: A PHP page does not mean that it's automatically interpretted as HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser treats the response as plaintext.

Prepend to you response a `Content-Type: text/html\`n  plus wrap your content inside an `<html></html>` tag.

Comment: if headers_sent(). he can't exactly send a Content-Type header can he?  The <html> tags would likely coerce a browser into seeing it as HTML though.

Comment: This works. All i did was add an echo "<html>" at the beginning of the function and a echo "</html>" at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way.

```
<?php
$yourURL="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
?>
```

Comment: Does not work. It returns paintext 
    location.href='./index.php'

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) and not have to deal with JavaScript or meta redirects at all?

```
<?php
// Top of your page
ob_start();

// Code goes here

// Redirect
if ($redirect_is_necessary)
{
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
}

// Rest of page goes here

// Bottom of page
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly fine. However I was hoping for only javascript redirection.